# Matching a string in a column in one dataframe with EITHER of two columns in another dataframe in R

Tags: r, matching

I have two dataframes df1 and df2. df1 includes a column df1$product with the name of a product. The second one includes three columns of interest here: df2$product_code, df2$product_name, and df2$product_aka_name.
I need to add a column df1$product_code in df1 based on matching on however the product is called (given that it can be known with two different names as listed in df2).

So far I have tried using match() after collating df2$product_name and df2$product_aka_name (which failed). I have also tried using grep() but had to stop after a few hours without any results. Finally, I looked into fuzzyjoin, but it seemed not appropriate to my problem.
The real datasets have respectively 700,000 rows and 20 columns for df1, and 40,000 rows and 5 columns for df2. So I would need something fast and efficient…

An MRE could be as follows:

```
df1 <- data.frame(product = c("Abcd", "Efgh", "Ijkl", "Mnop", "Qrst", "Uvwx"), col2 = c("DLK", "CBN", "ABC", "ZHU", "HSC", "LJK"), col3 = c("qdsf88", "sdf63", "dd995", "dgsg1", "xxx587", "dfr55"))
df1
          product      col2            col3
1         Abcd         DLK             qdsf88
2         Efgh         CBN             sdf63
3         Ijkl         ABC             dd995
4         Mnop         ZHU             dgsg1
5         Qrst         HSC             xxx587
6         Uvwx         LJK             dfr55

df2 <- data.frame(product_code = c("1001", "1002", "1003", "1004", "1005", "1006", "1007", "1008"), product_name = c("Fcde", "Abcd", "Efgh", "Mlfr", "Mnop", "Plor", "Kdlr", "Vfsd"), product_aka_name = c(NA, NA, NA, "Qrst", NA, "Uvwx", "Azer", "Qwer"))
df2
 product_code product_name product_aka_name
1         1001         Fcde             <NA>
2         1002         Abcd             <NA>
3         1003         Efgh             <NA>
4         1004         Mlfr             Qrst
5         1005         Mnop             <NA>
6         1006         Plor             Uvwx
7         1007         Kdlr             Azer
8         1008         Vfsd             Qwer
```

The result I need is as follows:

```
df1 <- data.frame(product = c("Abcd", "Efgh", "Ijkl", "Mnop", "Qrst", "Uvwx"), col2 = c("DLK", "CBN", "ABC", "ZHU", "HSC", "LJK"), col3 = c("qdsf88", "sdf63", "dd995", "dgsg1", "xxx587", "dfr55"), product_code = c("1002", "1003", NA, "1005", "1004", "1006"))
df1
 product col2   col3 product_code
1    Abcd  DLK qdsf88         1002
2    Efgh  CBN  sdf63         1003
3    Ijkl  ABC  dd995         <NA>
4    Mnop  ZHU  dgsg1         1005
5    Qrst  HSC xxx587         1004
6    Uvwx  LJK  dfr55         1006
```

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make it in two steps and update those with `NA`.

```
i <- match(df1$product, df2$product_name)
j <- is.na(i)
i[j] <- match(df1$product[j], df2$product_aka_name)
df2$product_code[i]
#[1] "1002" "1003" NA     "1005" "1004" "1006"
```

In case this is to slow use `fastmatch::fmatch` instead of `match` and maybe use `which(is.na(i))` instead of `is.na(i)`.

Or create one vector to match and use modulo `%%`.

```
i <- match(df1$product, c(df2$product_name, df2$product_aka_name))
i <- (i - 1) %% nrow(df2) + 1
df2$product_code[i]
```

Or create a vector of the indexes, set the names and use this to subset.

```
df2$product_code[setNames(rep(seq_len(nrow(df2)), 2),
        c(df2$product_name, df2$product_aka_name))[df1$product]]
#[1] "1002" "1003" NA     "1005" "1004" "1006"
```

---

Benchmark

```
library(data.table)
dt0 <- copy(df1)
dt2 <- copy(df2)
setDT(dt0); setDT(dt2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(setup = dt1 <- copy(dt0),
"data.table" = {
dt1[dt2,
    on = c("product" = "product_name"),
    code1 := i.product_code
][dt2,
    on = c("product" = "product_aka_name"),
    code2 := i.product_code
][, 
    product_code := fcoalesce(
        code1, code2
    )
][, `:=`(
    code1 = NULL,
    code2 = NULL
 )]
dt1$product_code},
base = {i <- match(df1$product, df2$product_name)
  j <- is.na(i)
  i[j] <- match(df1$product[j], df2$product_aka_name)
  df2$product_code[i] },
"dplyr-TarJae" = {df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = c("product" = "product_name")) %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = c("product" = "product_aka_name")) %>% 
  mutate(product_code = coalesce(product_code.x, product_code.y), .keep = "unused") %>% 
    select(-c(product_aka_name, product_name)) },
"dplyr-Ben Norris" = {df1 %>%
  left_join( # keeps all rows in df1 even if returns NA
    df2 %>%
      pivot_longer(cols = ends_with("name"), # pivots the columns with product names
                   values_to = "product", # names the new column to match df1
                   names_to = NULL) # discards old column names
  )}
)
```

Result

```
Unit: microseconds
             expr       min        lq        mean     median        uq       max neval
       data.table  1885.500  2050.626  2238.04686  2223.5400  2281.879  5869.183   100
             base    12.285    14.954    19.24151    19.7455    21.667    38.147   100
     dplyr-TarJae  5724.538  6041.483  6515.73361  6367.4275  6552.855 14358.221   100
 dplyr-Ben Norris 16517.120 17091.760 18016.42934 17427.3015 18800.145 22272.853   100
```

Comment: Woah, thank you so much! Works like a charm, and the code is almost as fast as your response. You made my day. 

Comment: Many thanks to all for your very generous help. Given the number of rows in my actual dataset, base R is the solution I need here.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a join strategy using functions from `dplyr` and `tiydr`. It works by pivoting `df2` into a longer form where each row is a name (included the aka names) matched with a product code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
  left_join( # keeps all rows in df1 even if returns NA
    df2 %>%
      pivot_longer(cols = ends_with("name"), # pivots the columns with product names
                   values_to = "product", # names the new column to match df1
                   names_to = NULL) # discards old column names
  )

Joining, by = "product"
  product col2   col3 product_code
1    Abcd  DLK qdsf88         1002
2    Efgh  CBN  sdf63         1003
3    Ijkl  ABC  dd995         <NA>
4    Mnop  ZHU  dgsg1         1005
5    Qrst  HSC xxx587         1004
6    Uvwx  LJK  dfr55         1006
```

Answer (score 2):

As you are looking for something fast and efficient, I would use [`data.table`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html) for this:

```r
library(data.table)

setDT(df1); setDT(df2)

df1[df2,
    on = c("product" = "product_name"),
    code1 := i.product_code
][df2,
    on = c("product" = "product_aka_name"),
    code2 := i.product_code
][, 
    product_code := fcoalesce(
        code1, code2
    )
][, `:=`(
    code1 = NULL,
    code2 = NULL
)]

df1
#    product col2   col3 product_code
# 1:    Abcd  DLK qdsf88         1002
# 2:    Efgh  CBN  sdf63         1003
# 3:    Ijkl  ABC  dd995         <NA>
# 4:    Mnop  ZHU  dgsg1         1005
# 5:    Qrst  HSC xxx587         1004
# 6:    Uvwx  LJK  dfr55         1006
```

`data.table` allows you to [modify by reference](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reference-semantics.html), which generally avoids creating copies of columns or data frames. This generally means that with large datasets it is faster than equivalent `tidyverse` approaches.

Answer (score 2):

We could do it this way using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = c("product" = "product_name")) %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = c("product" = "product_aka_name")) %>% 
  mutate(product_code = coalesce(product_code.x, product_code.y), .keep = "unused") %>% 
  select(-c(product_aka_name, product_name))

product col2   col3 product_code
1    Abcd  DLK qdsf88         1002
2    Efgh  CBN  sdf63         1003
3    Ijkl  ABC  dd995         <NA>
4    Mnop  ZHU  dgsg1         1005
5    Qrst  HSC xxx587         1004
6    Uvwx  LJK  dfr55         1006
```